# (AChartEngine) How to set default zoom rate? How to set custom font style?

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I use AChartEngine with my android project.

I have 2 questions when I implement a bar chart.

**First question**
Here is my bar chart when I just run on an emulator.

first picture

[image: ac]

It seems work perfectly, but It's view looks better when I press decrease zoom rate button at right-buttom zoom pane.

second picture

[image: gjj]

I want the chart shows like this but I don't want to click zoom rate button every time I display the chart. Can I set default zoom rate? So when I run on emulator, The chart will be showed like second picture instantly.

Here is my code

```
    XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Product Name1");
series1.add(1,15);

XYSeries series2 = new XYSeries("Product Name2");
series2.add(2,35);

XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();          
dataset.addSeries(series1);
dataset.addSeries(series2);


XYSeriesRenderer renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
renderer1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
renderer1.setDisplayChartValues(true);
renderer1.setChartValuesTextSize(20);

XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
renderer2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
renderer2.setDisplayChartValues(true);
renderer2.setChartValuesTextSize(20);

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);

    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle(chartTitle);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(-0.7);   
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

    mRenderer.setXTitle("Product");
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(3);

    mRenderer.setYTitle("Calorie (kCal)");
```

**Second question**
How to implement my custom font style (font style file is keep at asset folder) to the chart? I found only this method but it doesn't work.

```
mRenderer.setTextTypeface(typefaceName, style);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for your second question is

first download the ttf file of your required font from net,
    then create a folder named "assets", under it one more folder "fonts",
    put the .ttf file inside fonts folder.

then in your activity write this code:

```
Typeface type=Typeface.createFromAssest(getAssets(),"fonts/yourttffile.ttf");
```

and set where you want, say textview

```
textview.setTypeface(type);
```

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, AChartEngine tries to fit your data the best way possible. However, you can tweak this behavior:

```
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(min);
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(max);
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setYAxisMax(40);
```

For the second question, I think you should first investigate how to add a custom font into a regular Android application and then it may work in AChartEngine too.

Comment: Thanks very much for first question :D

For second question, I try my best to do but I can't.

I think that to extend class may help, but can't do;

Comment: public class CustomXYMultipleSeriesRenderer extends XYMultipleSeriesRenderer implements Serializable{
 
private Context context;
private Typeface REGULAR_TEXT_FONT =Typeface.create(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);
private String mTextTypefaceName = REGULAR_TEXT_FONT.toString();
private int mTextTypefaceStyle = Typeface.NORMAL; 
public CustomXYMultipleSeriesRenderer(Context c) {
super();
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
this.context=c;
REGULAR_TEXT_FONT = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "FontName.otf");
}

public void setCustomTypeFace(Typeface t){
REGULAR_TEXT_FONT = t;
}